# Show that Lorentzian metric restricts to Riemannian metric on hyperbolic space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

> Define the Lorentzian metric $\langle \ ,\ \rangle$ on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ by $\langle x, x \rangle = - x_0^2 + x_1^2 + \cdots + x_n^2$.  Let 
>   $$\mathbb{H}^n = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} | \langle x , x \rangle = -1, \ x_0 > 0 \}$$
>   Prove that $\langle \ , \ \rangle$ pulls back to a Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{H}^n$

Preliminary question / remark: Does specifying a quadratic form as above uniquely specify a metric?  Although I am familiar with the usual Lorentzian metric where $g_{11} = -1$, $g_{ii} = 1$ for $i \neq 1$, and $g_{ij} = 0$ for $i \neq j$, I do not see why specifying the quadratic form given above would uniquely determine the metric's value for all pairs: $\langle x , y \rangle$.

**Primary Question**:  How do I prove the desired result?  My first strategy was to try to write down explicitly the tangent space for any point in $\mathbb{H}^n$, but I have not been able to do so.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's actually being specified here is a hypersurface of codimension 1. That it happens to be specified by a quadratic form having a specific value is not the important part: it's that it's of the form $f(x) = c$.

Comment: @Chappers I know that $\mathbb{H}^n$ is a hypersurface.  That was not the point of my prelim question.  The prelim question was whether specifying $\langle x, x\rangle$ for all x automatically determined the value of $\langle x,y \rangle$ for all pairs x,y, which seems unlikely.  My guess is that the author of the problem was just imprecise in their language and assumed familiarity with the Lorentzian metric already, but I was not certain.

Comment: Ah, then you want https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarization_identity#Symmetric_bilinear_forms

Comment: @Chappers Yes, that answers my preliminary question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in the comments, given any quadratic form on a real vector space (such as an indefinite metric), one has
$$ Q(x+y)-Q(x)-Q(y) = 2B(x,y) \\
Q(x-y)-Q(x)-Q(y) = -2B(x,y) $$
by the definition. Subtracting and dividing gives
$$ B(x,y) = \frac{1}{4}(Q(x+y)-Q(x-y)), $$
or in this case,
$$ \langle x,y \rangle = \frac{1}{4}( \langle x+y,x+y \rangle - \langle x-y,x-y \rangle). $$
So given $\langle x,x \rangle $ for every $x$, we can find $\langle x,y \rangle$ for any $x$ and $y$.

---

We can parametrise the surface as
$$ \phi(y) = (\sqrt{1+\lVert \mathbf{y} \rVert^2},\mathbf{y}), $$
where $\mathbf{y} = (y_1,y_2,\dotsc,y_n)$.

The pullback metric is then given by $ h(X,Y) = (\phi^*g)(X,Y) = g(d\phi(X),d\phi(Y)) $. In coordinates,
$$ h_{ij} = g_{kl}\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial y_k} \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial y_l} = \delta_{ij} + \frac{y_i y_j}{1+\lVert \mathbf{y} \rVert^2}, $$
so
$$h_{ij} dy^i dy^j = \lVert dy \rVert^2 + \frac{(y \cdot dy)^2 }{1+\lVert y \rVert^2}, $$
where $\cdot$ is the ordinary Euclidean scalar product metric. This is bounded below by 
$$ \lVert dy \rVert^2 \left( 1-\frac{\lVert y \rVert^2}{1+\lVert y \rVert^2} \right) = \frac{\lVert{dy}\rVert^2}{1+\lVert y \rVert^2} > 0 $$
for $dy \neq 0$, and so is positive-definite.

Answer (score 2):

Geometrically, this is the upper sheet of the two-sheeted hyperboloid $x_0^2-x_1^2-\dots -x_n^2=1$.
Consider the smooth function $f\colon \mathbb{R}^{n+1}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(X)=g(X,X)$. Because of
\begin{align*}
T_Xf(Y_X)(h)=Y_X(h\circ f)&=\left. \frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} (h\circ f)(X+tY)\\
&=\left. \frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} h(f(X)+2tg(X,Y)+t^2g(Y,Y))=2g(X,Y)\left(\frac{d}{dt}\right)_{f(X)}h,
\end{align*}
we have $df_X(Y)=2g(X,Y)$, which yields $df_X=2X^{\flat}$.
Thus, $df_X$ has rank $1$ for any $X\neq 0$, and $-1$ is a regular value of $f$.
Then a regular level set $f^{-1}(\{-1\})$ is a smooth manifold, which also holds for $\mathbb{H}^n$.
Moreover, we have $T_X \mathbb{H}^n=\ker T_Xf=X^{\perp}$ for each $X\in \mathbb{H}^n$.
Because $g(X,X)=-1<0$, the restriction of the ambient metric to $X^{\perp}$ is positive definite,
so $g$ induces a Riemannian metric $\imath^* g$ on $\mathbb{H}^n$.